# AS3: Printjob Multipage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing, multipage

I'd like to print a big page (bigger than an A4 Paper), but the MC is getting cutted at the end of the page. Is flash able to print the other part of the MC on a second page?

My code:

```
buttonRgPrint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, printDocRg);
function printDocRg (MouseEvent):void{

    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

    if (printJob.start()) {

        printJob.addPage(myMC);
        printJob.send();
    }
}
```

Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing the page as a single page by [scaling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7df3.html)

The number of pixels depends on the dpi. [Check this out for more info](http://www.a4papersize.org/a4-paper-size-in-pixels.php)

```
buttonRgPrint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, printDocRg);
function printDocRg (MouseEvent):void{

    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

    if (printJob.start()) {
        myMC.width = 420; 
        myMC.height = 842;
        printJob.addPage(myMC);
        printJob.send();
    }
}
```